# Can you read the audio output of a linux process (or entire system) in real-time?

Tags: raspberry-pi, text-to-speech, audio-streaming

On my Raspberry Pi, I'm playing streaming speech from a python script to my USB speakers.  I want to flash/throb GPIO LEDs in sync with the syllables/words, but I don't know how to access the raw output of the speakers in real-time to sample the signal and set the LED brightness.  I'm thinking of something like tcpdump/wireshark but for audio instead of networking.

I would be happy with either monitoring the process itself generating the audio, or the audio from the system as a whole.

I have found solutions that work when you have discrete audio file and can preprocess it before playing it, but this is *streaming* audio being fed to the Pi over the internet.

Comment: You made a lot of statements but I don't see a question being asked here on SO which is a Q&A platform. You ask a specific question that should return a specific, fact-based answer. No opinion allowed. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]

Comment: I updated the post to be more specific about my question.  The statements were intended to show that I've tried a few different things before asking here, which someone might otherwise suggest.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)

Comment: I have rewritten it to be a more concrete, answerable question.  Sorry for the protocol violation

Comment: Perhaps your question would be better asked on the [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com), see their [ask topics](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: The explanation about the Raspberry Pi is for use-case context but not specific to a Pi.  I would like to know how to do this on any Linux system.